# Qt sending signal to static slot in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I find these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428038/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-signal-to-a-static-slot-without-a-receiver-instance), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153029/qt-designer-how-to-connect-a-signal-to-a-static-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859507/how-to-call-a-static-function-as-a-slot-in-qt), but no one can help me for my case because my slot is in another class and the answers is for static slot in the same class.
Consider this code:

```
class Util : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
         static void clean(); // static

    private:
        Util(QObject *parent=0): QObject(parent){} // be always static
};

class Handler: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
       Handler(QObject *parent=0): QObject(parent){}
    signals:
        void cleanup();
};
```

and **MainWindow** function **connectSignal();**

```
void MainWdindow::connectSignal()
{
    Handler *handler = new Handler();
   connect(handler, SIGNAL(cleanup), &Util::clean) // compile error 
}
```

the error is:

```
 no matching function for call MainWindow::connect(Handler*&, const char*, void(*)())
....
note: cannot convert Util::clean(type void(*)()) to type const QObject*
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**
Solved, solution in the comments

Comment: qt 5.6, windows && Linux

Comment: `connect(handler, &Handler::cleanup, &Util::clean)` should work with sufficiently recent Qt version.

Comment: `connect(handler, SIGNAL(cleanup), &Util::clean)` looks like you mixed Qt4 and Qt5 signal connection style, Try this instead: `QObject::connect(handler, &Handler::cleanup, &Util::clean);`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik It works !, thank you. One of you put this as answer to be accepted.

Comment: @Scheff  see above

Comment: @Phiber https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251898/qt-multithreading-how-to-update-two-qlabels/45251994#45251994